# Returning multiple values: Return array vs change referenced parameters

Tags: php, arrays, parameters, reference, return

When I need to return multiple values as result of my function (For example, let's say a boolean stating if a specific operation was successful, and a message stating the error or success message), should I return those multiple values in an array, or by making the function arguments be references and change their value?

```
function myFunction($input){
    ...
    return array("success" => true/false, "message" => "Internal Error"/"Success");
}
```

Or

```
function myFunction($input, &$success, &$message){
    ...
    $success = true;
    $message = "It worked";
}
```

What would be considered best practice? I've already seen both in various codebases, even in other languages.

Comment: Why should someone use their flash message variables as references? I'm not comfortable with it so I ignore it.

Comment: I don't see any need for a message when the operation was successful, so you could return true on success and on failure you return the error message.

Comment: @revo Using messages was just an example. (Well, it's kind of how I got the question in the first place, but I'm interested in an answer for other types of return values as well)

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I'm really not a fan of returning different types of return values depending on what happens. It feels really wrong. If the function returns an array, it should always return an array. If it returns a integer, it should always return an integer. And so on. Also, as stated in my previous comment, messages were just an example :)

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Also, in my case, there are multiple "cases" of success that all come with a specific message. (But again, I'm interested in a generic answer regarding other types of return values as well)

Comment: According to this logic a function that returns `NULL` should always return `NULL`. :) Sorry, but you should remove that habit. You return from your function what you need and what you can work the best with. If an array suits your need the best, return an array.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I got that habit from other programming languages were the return type is specified in the function definition. And, honestly, I think that such a constraint is useful because developers will also know what to expect. Which can avoid lots of ugly if-else testing. And, yes, in my case an array would suit me best - But I know that the other version I mentioned is also being used by some people, so I'm wondering which way can be considered best practice, since the second version, while messier, would generate less overhead (I think?).

Comment: The second method is being used by some built-in php functions (e.g. `exec`). It's probably the better method out of the two (unless you're going to output it anyway (e.g. as JSON)).

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Ok, thanks! Will you post your reply as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Ah, just another thing: What about returning one value (For example the success bool) and changing the other by its reference (Message for example)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It really depends on your use-case and what suits your need the best. Both methods can be used, while the second methods is used by some built-in PHP functions (e.g. `exec`). If you don't need an array from the beginning since you don't output it (e.g. as JSON), you should go with references and might just return `true` or `false` depending on the successful completion or not. If you once need the message, you can then just use the variable you referenced.

```
function myFunction($input, &$return_message) {
    if($input ...) {
        $return_message = 'action 1 successfully';
        return true;
    } else {
        $return_message = 'invalid input';
    }

    return false;
}

$msg = "";
$action = myFunction(array('Hello'), $msg);
if($action === true) {
    echo 'Action completed!';
} else {
    die('Action not successfully, error message: '.$msg);
}
```